# Accessing elements in a Array that is dynamically generated PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have what I think is an interesting problem and I am looking for a better solution than the one I can think of.

I have a POST array returning in my php code that contains an array of elements that is generated dynamically and its length is different depending on the user.

Example

```
Array = (
[element-1] = a,
[element-2] = b,
[element-3] = c,
[non-element] = something,
[another-non-element] = something
)
```

Now, in my php code, I need to call a function for every element (not the non-elements)

Example

```
$element= $_POST['element-1'];
saveElements(element);
```

So I am trying to think of a good way of going through the entire array and picking out the elements. without doing something like:

```
$i = 1;
foreach($_POST as obj){
if(obj == 'element-' + $i)

$element= $_POST['element-' + $i];
saveElements(element);

}
```

I'm worried because this assume the order is correct.

Any better suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's better to make your `$_POST` look like below

```
Array = (
    [elements] = [a, b, c],
    [non-element] = something,
    [another-non-element] = something
)
```

so that you can just iterate `$_POST['elements']`

```
foreach($_POST['elements'] as $element) {
    saveElements($element);
}
```

Comment: Similar to what I said above, these elements come from different places so I don't really have access to do them all in one elements array

Answer (score 1):

If it is a form you can generate your inputs and set name attribute of for every one of them for "element[]". Then $_POST[element] is an array of elements you have generated.

```
foreach($_POST['element'] as $index => $value){
    saveElement($value);
}
```

Considering the comment below this would be better:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
    preg_match('#element-\d#i', $key, $found);
    if(isset($found[0]))
        saveElement($val);
}
```

Comment: Sadly, these elements are all coming from the same place so I don't think I can put them in just element.

Comment: Then something like this would be better:


`foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
    preg_match('#element-\d#i', $key, $found);
    if(isset($found[0]))
        saveElement($val);
}`